# Is there another way to check if variables are equal? When I use this code I didn't have any result

Tags: plsqldeveloper

When I check if variables are equal, I don't have any result. When I run the procedure, is there any way to check the value of variables?

```
procedure c  is
i_n number:=0;
o_n    number:=0;
c_t number;
cursor c_values is
SELECT
    a.file_type AS file_type,a.input AS a_input,b.input AS b_input,a.output AS a_output,b.output AS b_output,
    CASE WHEN a.input = b.input then
             i_n+1

         WHEN a.output = b.output  THEN 
              o_n+1
    End case
FROM
  test1 a, test4 b
         where a.file_type=b.file_type
        ;
begin
select count(*) into c_t from test1;
if i_n=c_t and o_n=c_t then
dbms_output.put_line('done');
end if;
end;`
end;
```

Comment: Please post table rows from test1 & test4.

Comment: Also, your `CASE` has no `ELSE`.  Did you mean to have a zero result there, instead of NULL?